# Tensorflow: Is there a language to define graphs or are they only built via API?

Tags: tensorflow, scheme, lisp, grammar

Tensorflow seems like a candidate for a language to define [Graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs).
Just need an appropriate grammar. LISP/Scheme could contain it.

Is there a language to define graphs or are they only built via API?

Comment: Although this sort of thing probably is a good use of Lisp, I suspect the practical answer would be a graph definition language in YAML or JSON, with a Python interface to that.  Such things might exist: I don't know enough about Tensorflow to know.